# ps3joy slow output

Tags: ros, ps3joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using p3joy to get feedback from my ps3 controller on an Odroid u2 running Ubuntu 12.10, however it is incredibly slow. There appears to be a delay of a few seconds before messages arrive regarding changes of the controller. evtest and jstest give me the same kind of delay. I 'debugged' ps3joy_node.py and it does seem like its update function is called often enough, where could this delay then be coming from?

In addition, I noticed that if I don't move the controller (this also happens on a laptop with Ubuntu), no events get sent. For example if I keep the controller laying still and press the X button, no messages/events are being sent. If I then move the controller slightly, I get the message/event.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102676/ps3joy-slow-output/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update (4/21):
I found a PPA that contains a different PS3 driver:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sixaxis#Quick_Setup_Guide_for_12.10

I currently recommend installing this, then:
sudo  sixad --start
rosrun joy joy_node

You should see usable output now.

---

OK I just ran into this issue.  Here's what I know:

I see rates through rostopic hz that are absolutely terrible (1.5Hz through 6 to maybe 10 Hz).  Even --continuous-output doesn't help.  I expect something around 40Hz normal and 90Hz using --continuous-output.  Tried multiple dongles, built-in bluetooth, nothing worked.

I tried it on another computer and it worked perfectly there.  Eventually I found out that it's due to the kernel version.  The latest kernel that works for me is way back to linux-generic-quantal (3.5).  3.8 and 3.11 are both terribly broken.

You can try testing this by installing the linux-generic-quantal package, then holding shift as your computer boots and selection "previous kernels" -> 3.5 from the grub menu.  Let me know if this resolves it for you as well.  If you don't need a newer kernel, I would uninstall any later kernels and stick with quantal's kernel.

As for fixing this, I have no idea in the slightest.  I would personally ask @ahendrix as he was my go to Kernel guy at Willow Garage.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-01-16**:
I tried to install 3.5, but all my drivers stopped working (including bluetooth and internet), so I couldn't test it there. I tried 3.13rc8, it still gives the same frequency (around 13hz for me). Adding continuous output does not change anything for me.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-01-16**:
I just tried it on an old Pandaboard with Ubuntu and kernel 3.1, it gave me 40hz there. Curious :)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-17**:
Sadly, I don't have a PS3 controller, so I can't play around with this. @chad-rockey if you have one that I can borrow, I could play around with it. I'm also interested to see if the newer kernels have native support for the PS3 controller.

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2014-01-17**:
@ahendrix, Yeah, please feel free to drop by Savioke and borrow one.  I also have two USB bluetooth adapters if you want to borrow those, though it doesn't seem to make a difference between an X230, ASUS Bluetooth, and el-cheapo Bluetooth.

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2014-02-19**:
Hi @Hansg91 are you fixed the problem slow output in new kernels? I need working bluetooth joystick with kernel 3.8 and BeagleBone Black. I dont understand where to begin to solve...

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-02-21**:
Nop, no idea. I just know its due to the kernel now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem with slow output on BeagleBone Black Ubuntu 13.04 and kernel 3.8.
I used [this](http://booting-rpi.blogspot.ro/2012/08/dualshock-3-and-raspberry-pi.html) great instruction.
But I had problem with compile sixad:

```
error: ... was not declared in this scope
```

It can be fixed by adding `unistd.h` to sources files.

With my bluetooth adapter, joystick became detected after `echo "DisablePlugins = input" >> /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Rates through rostopic hz 60-70 Hz

---

Originally posted by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) with karma: 85 on 2014-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2014-04-21**:
This works, I found a PPA:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sixaxis#Quick_Setup_Guide_for_12.10

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2014-04-21**:
Yes, I've seen it. But not in this PPA version for arm-linux :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those that are curious, you can make the ps3 gamepad rumble, both in wired and wireless (sixad). I wrote a thin wrapper, which is based on fftest:

https://github.com/anqixu/sixad_rumble

(You will need to identify the proper /dev/input/event# handle associated to your gamepad. I use 'ls'.)

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2014-12-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1